# Objective-C:Get a Wrong Output and I don't Why when I sort NSMutableSet

Tags: objective-c, sorting, nsmutableset

I was sorting an nsmutableSet but I met a weird problem.

```
   NSArray *data = @[@[@"1",@"2",@"3"],
                   @[@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",@"6"],
                   @[@"8",@"9",@"10"],
                   @[@"15",@"16",@"17",@"18"]];

NSArray *sortArr = [[NSArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *Data = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSMutableSet *interSection = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];
interSection = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:[data objectAtIndex:0]];

NSSortDescriptor *sort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"description" ascending:YES ];

for (int i =1; i < 4; i ++) {
    if ([interSection intersectsSet:[NSSet setWithArray:[data objectAtIndex:i]]]) {
        [interSection unionSet:[NSSet setWithArray:[data objectAtIndex:i]]];
    }
    else{

        sortArr = [interSection sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];
        [Data addObject:sortArr];
        interSection = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:[data objectAtIndex:i]];

    }
}

if ([interSection count] != 0) {

    sortArr = [interSection sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];
    [Data addObject:sortArr];
}
NSLog(@"%@",Data);
```

but the output is :
           (
        1,
        2,
        3,
        4,
        5,
        6
    ),
        (
        10,
        8,
        9
    ),
        (
        15,
        16,
        17,
        18
    )
)

why it is(10,8,9) but (8,9,10) ?

Anyone knows the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `NSSortDescriptor` for string so it it sorts in string way (8>10, 9>10). You should create a custom `NSSortDescriptor` like this:

```
NSSortDescriptor * sort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"sort" ascending:YES comparator:^(id obj1, id obj2) {

    if ([obj1 integerValue] > [obj2 integerValue]) {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
    }
    if ([obj1 integerValue] < [obj2 integerValue]) {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
    }
    return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
}];
sortArr = [[data objectAtIndex:i] sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject: sort]];
```

Comment: Thank you anhtu.Your answer is right.By the way,when I tried to init my array in this way data = @[@[@1,@2,@3].....] or this way data = @[@[@[nsnumber numberwithint:1],@[nsnumber numberwithint:2]...]]..I still couldnt get a right anwser.Do you know why?

Comment: I think it sorts NSNumber like an object(maybe like string, I'm not sure), it doesn't get intValue of NSNumber. Because it can't know NSNumber is char, float, int or ...

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you're using strings and not numbers. When sorting strings, 10 comes before 8 because it starts with a 1.

Comment: I fellow your idea and change my array to this                                 NSArray *data = @[@[@1,@2,@3],
                       @[@2,@3,@4,@5,@6],
                       @[@8,@9,@10],
                       @[@15,@16,@17,@18]];   the output is not correct.....